# How can an attacker (hacker) hijack an http connection

Tags: ssl

I am watching [this](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-858-computer-systems-security-fall-2014/video-lectures/lecture-14-ssl-and-https/) lecture on SSL. Here professor Zeldovich says that if a connection is http, a hacker could lead you to believe that you are talking to Amazon.com, while in fact you are talking to his (the hackers) server.

How does that happen? For example amazon.com is mapped to an ip. If my computer sends a request to ip address A and is waiting for a response on say some port a, how can a hacker from ip address B send a response to my port a and make me believe it came from ip address A? I understand the part where the attacker can eavesdrop and read my un-encrypted data. But unless he hacks my DNS server too and misleads me into believing that ip address B belongs to Amazon.com, I don't understand how a hacker might impersonate Amazon.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way it can be accomplished is via a man in the middle attack further explained here, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack.

Someone intercepts your request to a site like Amazon or a bank and pretends to be them. Even if you type in Amazon.com in your browser and it gets resolved to Amazons IP, someone can intercept the request before it gets there. That's why SSL is so important because then you can verify that you're actually talking to Amazon or your bank.

Answer (score 1):

1. There's no restriction that an attacker might not be influencing your DNS -- for example, it's a cheap way of redirecting a lot of interesting traffic through ones own network to just modify the default DNS server your home router uses.
2. The classical Man-In-The-Middle might really be just that: sitting between you and amazon, modifying your communication as desired. I fact, [there's North American ISPs](http://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2013/04/how-a-banner-ad-for-hs-ok/) who (used to?) do that to inject their own ads.
3. often, you're not even sure that you're talking to *exactly* `amazon.com`; maybe you're just not seeing the `ä` in `amäzon.com`. UTF and Punycode make this a whole new cluster of attack possibilities.
4. there's a lot of ways to poison your DNS cache. For example, DNS is based on UDP. If you just spam a computer with DNS replies fast enough, you're bound to answer an actual request "by accident" sooner or later (that is, unless you get blocked for doing so, or someone is using DNSsec etc.).